# If with copy paste in last row

Tags: excel, vba

In my excel sheet i want to copy the data from last row/same row of column E K M AF AI, if a condition is met in column AF =Concrete and paste it another sheet in different location

```
Dim FinalRow As Long
LR = lastrow

LR = Worksheets("MASTER LOG-1").Range("AF" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If LR = "concrete" Then
```

Worksheets

```
Dim FinalRow As Long
LR = lastrow

LR = Worksheets("MASTER LOG-1").Range("AF" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If LR = "concrete" Then
```

Worksheets

if a condition is met in column AF =Concrete then copy data from same row of match in column E ,K,M,AF,AI

Answer (score 0):

This should help you well underway.

```
Sub Copy_Concrete()

    Dim lastr As Integer
    lastr = Worksheets("MASTER LOG-1").Range("AF" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'determine last row of column AF
    If Worksheets("MASTER LOG-1").Range("AF" & lastr) = "Concrete" Then 'If lastrow of AF = concrete then
        Worksheets("Some other sheet").Range("Your range").Value = Worksheets("MASTER LOG-1").Range("Whichevercolumn", lastr).Value 'Set whichever range on another sheet to the value on the same row whichever column of your match.
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for ur help                     Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 Dim lastr As Integer
 
    lastr = Worksheets("MASTER LOG-1").Range("AF" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    If Worksheets("MASTER LOG-1").Range("AF" & lastr) = "CONCRETE" Then
    
    Worksheets("MASTER LOG-1").Range("E", lastr).Value = Worksheets("CST").Range("F8").Value
    
    
    End If

End Sub
it is showing debug

Comment: Please edit your question with updated code, its very hard to read in comments. Also I think you have your target and source swapped in the last statement. Where you want the value to go comes before the `=`, and where it comes from comes after.